# using requests for google form

Tags: python, https, python-requests, google-forms

I wanted to automate a google form response using request library in python.
I get the response <200> yet when I check for the data my form received it shows nothing.
when I record the response in a html file, it shows a page that appears when your response in summited.
Here is my code:

```
import string
import requests
import random
Url = 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeI3-jkg0oedRXECibaxbGZiFyOHGYjvNiOXcADBK9Qq__gUg/formResponse'
tex = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase,k = random.randint(10,20)))
Data = {'entry.583812596': 2,
'entry.1023010593': tex,
'dlut': 1632588905384,
'entry.583812596_sentinel': '',
'fvv': 1,
'draftResponse': '[null,null,"5072897323996825438"]',
'pageHistory': 0,
'fbzx': 3591581611209877868}
a = requests.post(url= Url , data = Data)
print (a)
open('iindex.html','w').write(a.text)
```

Comment: It's seems like your form accepts form even if user didn't mark any answer. Check if your data is correct for google forms.

Comment: requests is sending data to your google forms, and the response you are getting that it's recorded which is present in `a.text` or `a.content`. Now if google form did not receive this data, so you need to review the json you are passing. for example is `entry.583812596` correct along with other keys also check if any header is needed or so, so request.post is acceptable from google forms.